# jupyter no reconoce !ls, !cat, !head

Tags: jupyter

Al ejecutar estos comandos en jupyter notebook, obtengo los errores:

> "`head`" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o
>   archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>
> ---
>
> "`ls`" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o
>   archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>
> ---
>
> "`cat`" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o
>   archivo por lotes ejecutable.

¿Cual puede ser el problema?.

Comment: Me parece que estás ejecutando comandos de linux en un entorno windows o te falta PowerShell.

Comment: En Windows 10, tengo instalado Anaconda 3. Utilizando Anaconda prompt, arranco jupiter notebook en la carpeta en la que tengo el notebook que voy a abrir. Las primeras sentencias de este notebook son las comentadas. Espero que esto  aclare algo más mi situación y puedas indicarme qué más puedo hacer.

Comment: Efectivamente. He probado en un ordenador con Linux y funciona correctamente. Buscaré en Internet información sobre PowerShell

Comment: Le has dado click a `new` > `terminal` ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas utilizando comandos de linux en un ordenador con Windows probablemente. Tendrás que cambiar los comandos (head, ls, cat) por los correspondientes en Windows CMD.

Usa estos:

- Para ls --> dir
- Para head and cat --> type